# Persisting non-owning side object in Hibernate @ManyToMany bidirectional mapping does not persist data in joining table

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to implement ManyToMany bidirectional mapping in Hibernate. But, when I test the application by persisting non-owning side object, Hibernate does not persist data in join table.

**Here is my code:**

**College.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="college")
public class College {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="college_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="college_name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="colleges",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Certification> certifications;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**Certification.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="certification")
public class Certification {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="certification_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="certification_name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="certification_college",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="certification_id"),inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="college_id"))
    private Set<College> colleges;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**MainApplication.java:**

```
public class MainApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Certification certification1 = new Certification();
        certification1.setName("Java");

        Certification certification2 = new Certification();
        certification2.setName("C++");

        Set<Certification> certifications = new HashSet<Certification>();
        certifications.add(certification1);
        certifications.add(certification2);

        College college1 = new College();
        college1.setName("ABC");
        college1.setCertifications(certifications);

        College college2 = new College();
        college2.setName("XYZ");
        college2.setCertifications(certifications);

        SessionFactory sessionFactory =  HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(college1);
        session.save(college2);

        transaction.commit();
        sessionFactory.close(); 
    }
}
```

**Here's the SQL Output:**

```
Hibernate: insert into college (college_name) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into certification (certification_name) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into certification (certification_name) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into college (college_name) values (?)
```

**Thank you.**

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the @JoinTable annotation in your College.java class. You're persisting an entity that is not aware of the table that maps the relationship.

Add the following code after the @ManyToMany annotation of the "certifications" attribute.

```
@JoinTable(name="certification_college",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="college_id"),inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="certification_id"))
```

Comment: that throw  
`code` org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Associations marked as mappedBy must not define database mappings like @JoinTable or @JoinColumn: com.hibernate.associations.College.certifications 
error.

Comment: remove the mappedBy attribute, it becomes @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)

Comment: Thanks. That worked. 
But I have one question, since we removed mappedBy attribute, how does Hibernate know which side takes responsibility of mapping?
And in our case is it the College class that performed the mapping task or the Certification class?

Comment: The DB table that maps  the relation is the associative table "certification_college" that associates certifications with colleges, hence the "responsability of mapping" it's its. If you persist an entity with a ManyToMany annotation then you must specify which column  contains the PK of the current object (joinColumns) and which column will have the PK of the corresponding object (inverse ), in the associative table. If you look into your DB schema you'll see how neither colleges and certifications reference each other directly. ManyToMany is how we represent the associative table in JPA.